# Assign a separate theme to product pages and categories

Tags: magento2, product, category, theme, configuration

I have magento 2 and a requirement to show a certain category, subcategories and product pages in those categories using a different layout then other product pages on my store.

So just to be clear:

- I have a category page which shows a list of subcategories
- I have a sub category page which shows a list of products
  and a product page

each one of the above has a different functionality then other categories/products of my site.

So, I have a theme that I created that I assigned to the category and the subcategories that I need. It works great. But, I did not find a way to assign a theme to a product page. I had to assign the theme to the entire site for the theme to be applied to product pages. This defeats what I need to do

Am I missing something? What is the right approach?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/design/schedule.html

Answer (score 0):

So here the general idea I would follow:

- create a global theme for all your pages EXCEPT the product page
- create a specific theme ONLY for your product page
- assign your global theme to your entire site
- in your product configuration, enable your product specific theme (under **Schedule Design Update**)

[image]

Comment: your approach will work, but takes a lot of effort. I have to assign a theme to each product and if i change a theme, i must do it on every single product

Comment: actually this is what i wanted. I wish it could inherit the theme from the category. would make my life easier

Comment: @OvedYavine you can totally inherit the product specific theme from your global theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html